# How can I test the require function in PHPUnit? Expect E_COMPILE_ERROR

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I found error testing in the documentation:

```
$this->expectError();
$this->expectErrorMessage('foo');
\trigger_error('foo', \E_USER_ERROR);
```

But this does not work for my example:

```
$this->expectError();
$this->expectErrorMessageMatches( '/test/' );
require 'test.php';
```

Because require it's E_COMPILE_ERROR. I did not find in the documentation how I can test this point?

Comment: But if the code can't even be compiled, why would you need to test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work for me. Before error add this code:

```
$this->expectException( Error::class );
```